# How to create overlaid histograms sas with short format data?

Tags: graph, sas, histogram

I have data like this:

```
var1  target
1.2   X
2     Y
2.3   Z
```

I want to overlay the histograms with percents to look like something like this:

[image: Histogram image]

The graphs could be stacked as well as long as they are comparative.  I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
proc univariate data=mydata;
  var var1;
  by target;
  histogram;
run;
```

Comment: Do you need the smooth line as well as the histogram?

Comment: The smooth line would be nice but is not necessary.  I will give your code a try when I get back into the office.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SAS 9.4m3, the OVERLAY option was added to the HISTOGRAM statement in PROC UNIVARIATE. That means you can now get the graph you want directly from PROC UNIVARIATE:

```
proc Univariate data=sashelp.iris;
class Species;
var SepalLength;
histogram SepalLength / kernel overlay;
run;
```

In PROC SGPLOT, SAS 9.4m2 introduced support for the GROUP= option on the HISTOGRAM statement. So you if you prefer PROC SGPLOT, you can convert the data to long form and use the GROUP= option.

```
proc sgplot data=sashelp.iris;
histogram SepalLength / group=Species  transparency=0.5;
density SepalLength/ group=Species type=kernel;
run;
```

For more on overlaying and paneling histograms, see the article ["Comparative histograms: Panel and overlay histograms in SAS"](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2016/03/09/comparative-panel-overlay-histograms-sas.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to get them together in a panel:

```
data have_data;
  call streaminit(7);
  do _j = 1 to 1e3;
      do _i = 1 to 3;
        target=byte(_i+120);
        var1=rand('Normal',_i,0.5);
        output;
      end;
  end;
run;

proc sgpanel data=have_data;
  panelby target/columns=1;
  histogram var1;
  density var1;
run;
```

That's not overlaid, of course.  Overlaid is more challenging, and I think requires some additional steps.

To do overlaid, the simplest option is probably to split the `var1` into three variables, one per target value.  (For other target values, it can be blank.)  Then you create three histograms and density plots all in one `SGPLOT` call.

```
data want;
  set have_Data;
  array vars[3];
  vars[rank(target)-120] = var1;
run;
title;
proc sgplot data=want noautolegend;
  histogram vars1/name='x' legendlabel='x';
  histogram vars2/name='y' legendlabel='y';
  histogram vars3/name='z' legendlabel='z';
  density vars1;
  density vars2;
  density vars3;
  keylegend 'x' 'y' 'z'/position=top;
run;
```

I think you can also do this using `gtl` if you know that and/or are comfortable learning it, as that allows you to overlay the histograms, and if that is desired I can probably mock something up.